# Каким способом образовано слово зачётка?

Tags: словообразование

Каким способом образовано слово ЗАЧЁТКА? Суффиксальный - ошибка.

Comment: Надеюсь, таких спорных заданий в ЕГЭ не будет.Мои дети бы ответили "суффиксальный", а должны бы ответить "неморфологический". Оказывается, здесь слияние всех способов,т.е."лексико-морфолого-синтаксический". Не подозревала, что такой существует. Так ответили в Институте русского языка (там учится моя выпускница, она и спросила на кафедре). Так что век живи-век учись. Соан ответила по Валгиной и Розенталю.Это тоже возможный ответ. А Виктор верно определил "неморфологический", только аббревиатуры к нему не относятся.Так что оказалась права Соан.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы знаете,  иногда в такие языковые дебри заходишь, что вроде бы как и знаешь правила, а ломаешь голову, правильно или нет сказала\написала. А что уже говорить об учениках\студентах?! Очень много разбежностей  в словарях, на сайте "Грамота.ру" с тем же справочником по грамматике Розенталя, которым я руководствуюсь в своей работе. Конечно, спасибо всем участникам и организаторам этого форума за умные вопросы и  ответы, за дотошный поиск нужного и необходимого материала, за толерантность.

Comment: Ага, а в Институте русского языка открыли тот же учебник Валгиной и Розенталя, но дочитали цитируемый @Соан параграф до конца:

> ...Такой же способ обнаруживается и при образовании бытовых 
> наименований различных круп - пшенка, гречка, овсянка, а также 
> других пищевых изделий - тушенка, жженка.
> 
> Поскольку в данном типе словообразования участвуют суффиксальные 
> элементы, то его можно отнести и к морфолого-синтаксическому, а 
> точнее - лексико-морфолого-синтаксическому.


http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-048.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Среди 10 (если я не ошибаюсь) способов словообразования есть лексико-синтаксическое. Оно имеет место в случаях образования слов из словосочетаний, объединенных в одно слово в процессе употребления в языке, например: сумасшедший (с ума сшедший),наконец (на конец). При образовании слов из словосочетаний (часто это прилагательное + существительное) обычно происходит своеобразная словообразовательная компрессия: на базе прилагательного образуется имя существительное (с помощью суффикса -к), а определяемое имя вовсе опускается. Такое свертывание двухсловных наименований в одно особенно характерно для нашего времени и распространено в разговорном стиле: пятиэтажка (пятиэтажный дом), оборонка (оборонная промышленность), наличка (наличные деньги), высотка (высотное здание), *зачетка (зачетная книжка),*  визитка (визитная карточка) и др. Такой же способ обнаруживается и при образовании бытовых наименований различных круп - пшенка, гречка, овсянка, а также других пищевых изделий - тушенка, жженка. 
Так что  слово "зачетка" образовано с помощью суф.-к-. Интересно, конечно, выслушать другие мнения.

Comment: Такой способ относится к неморфологическим и называется (условно) слияние слов: сейчас, сегодня, заблагорассудится, но в слове "зачетка" такого слияния нет, а похоже это на сложение основ сложносокращенных, как, к примеру "вуз"

Comment: Лексико-синтаксический здесь присутствует: из словосочетания.Но и морфологический есть - с помощью суффикса - к-, и  морфолого-синтаксический (переход прилагательного в существительное, как, например, запятая, булочная, лесничий).Так как его определить? Вот если в ЕГЭ встретится, что писать ученику?

Comment: Вы знаете, Людмила, наверное,  это правило нужно  понять и запомнить.
Ученику всегда сложнее понять то, что мы по надобности только повторяем.

Comment: Слово "вуз" относится к  инициальным аббревиатурам, а именно к звуковым. А сущ-е "зачетка" образовано на базе прилагательного с помощью суффикса -к. Так что это разные словообразования.

Comment: А почему на базе прилагательного? Корневое понятие - зачет, способ проверки знаний учащихся. Если бы существовал зачетный журнал, его бы прозвали - 'зачет/ник', непосредственно от слова зачет; конник - от конь, общинник - от община, а не от 'конный человек, всадник' и 'общинный представитель'. Чем проще, тем ясней. От прилагательного в зачетке нет никаких следов. В словах нефтянка или землянка есть, а в зачетке или конке (конно-железной дороге) нет. Непонятно все-таки, зачем вместо простого объяснения (**зачет**-к-а), предлагать учащимся многосложное : зачет{ная}-к-а {книжка}.

Comment: "Если бы существовал зачетный журнал"- а разве он сейчас не существует? Вы давно были студентом? Как называется то, куда ставят зачёты? У меня было написано "Зачётная книжка". А у Вас? А в разговоре мы сокращаем: зачётка. Как же нет следов прилагательного? Вы просто не вдумались.

Comment: А если представить, что слово зачетка и словосочетание зачетная книжка практически одновременно образовались от базовой основы **зачет**? Неужели и **силач** произошел от 'сильного человека', а не прямо от **силы**. Где следы прилагательного в силаче и, повторюсь, в зачетке? Во главе словообразования стоит корень, основа, никак не более поздний продукт. Впрочем, это мое личное мнение...

Comment: Во главе словообразования стоит словообразовательный тип или, упрощённо говоря, аналогия. 

Это очень продуктивный способ словообразования, в котором новое слово мотивируется словосочетанием (а не одним словом), а суффикс прилагательного (или причастия) усекается:

раскладушка, продлёнка, маршрутка, пятиэтажка, касторка, нержавейка, кочегарка, пятилетка...

Comment: "След" слова _книжка_ можно заметить в том, что зачетка тоже женского рода.  Впрочем, мои студенты называют курсовую работу "курсовик" и даже противным словом "курсач". Хотя мы говорили просто "курсовая"

Comment: Слова образуются спонтанно, без правил. Пилот - пилотка. Или непременно надо сюда притянуть 'пилотный головной убор'?  Водолазка : это женщина-водолаз или водолазный свитер? да без разницы. К зачетке можно присовокупить методичку и рапортичку. Методичка - от методический, не спорю; рапортичка -??
Слова сами собой находят нужную им форму. Тема интересная, но длинная слишком. Противоречивая.

Answer (score 2):

Если суффиксальный способ - ошибка, то остается одно: слово  "зачетка" образовалось путем сложения основ от словосочетания "зачетная книжка" (сложносокращенное "зачет" от "зачетная" и "к" от "книжка")

Comment: Что от "зачётная книжка" - однозначно. Сложения основ не может быть, -К- здесь точно суффикс, смотрела словарь строения слов, да и сама не сомневаюсь.

Comment: Если это из ЕГЭ, посомневайтесь в источнике. Ошибок - тьма. Для ЕГЭ, на мой, взгляд, это суффиксальный способ образования.

Comment: Сокращение, например, для улицы Первомайской — Первомайка. По вашей логике выходит, что "к" взялась из "улица", но это, конечно, не так. "К" здесь является суффиксом, который намекает на определяемое слово.

Answer (score 0):

Новые слова типа ЗАЧЕТКА, НАЛИЧКА, ВИЗИТКА,  ПЯТИЭТАЖКА,... образуются на базе словосочетаний путем своеобразной словообразовательной компрессии: на базе имени прилагательного образуется имя существительное с суффиксом -К-, а определяемое имя существительное отсекается.

Это активный способ словообразования в современном русском языке.
 Его можно назвать, по моему мнению, лексико-морфолого-синтаксическим:

1) увеличивается семантический объем (предмет+его признак в одном слове),

2)было: имя прилагательное + имя существительное ---> имя существительное,

3) было: определение и определяемое слово ЗАЧЕТНАЯ КНИЖКА (связь согласование) 
---> появилось одно слово.

Answer (score 0):

В словаре Ефремовой обозначен суффикс К, который используется для образования существительных, обозначающих предмет со значением характерного признака, названного прилагательным, например:  клеёный - клеёнка, овсяный - овсянка, ветряной - ветрянка, массовый - массовка.

Мотивирующее слово названо, суффикс обозначен, к чему выдумывать какую-то словообразовательную компрессию. Такую компрессию можно увидеть во многих случаях: купальный костюм - купальник, черновой вариант - черновик. Это тоже лексико-морфолого-синтаксический способ образования?